# Linear RGB to Stockman-Sharpe LMS conversion

Tags: color, coordinate-transformation

I'm working on a psychophysical project that aims to emulate LMS cone responses accurately. My final goal is to transform linear RGB coordinates to physiologically relevant LMS responses (Stockman Sharpe LMS).

I've attempted doing this via two methods.

***Method 1***

The first was to convert the Stiles and Burch RGB distribution (1959) to Stockman Sharpe LMS. There is a conversion matrix given in the CIE 170-1 report which achieves the same.

[image: RGB spectra to LMS responses]

My first question is, given that the RHS graph above (Stockman LMS) is my final goal, how do I convert from linear RGB (or even sRGB) to that RGB CMF on the left of the above diagram, so that I could then make the final RGB->LMS transform?

***Method 2***

Another method I had for such a conversion was to first transform from linear RGB (or sRGB) to XYZ colour space (D65). I do know how to convert from the XYZ spectral space shown below to the Stockman LMS, but I'm not sure if the linearRGB->XYZ(D65) transformation brings the linear RGB signals to this spectral space. If not, I'd like to learn to make that transformation (XYZ (D65) -> CIE 2012 2 deg XYZ CMF...?)), so that I could finally move that over to the Stockman LMS space.

[image: CIE XYZ space]

I realise that I can transform the XYZ (D65) to a Bradford LMS space but that's not physiologically strong enough for my purposes, so I'd prefer to convert to Stockman LMS if possible.

Comment: There has been done some work on that problem  Google: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Mathematica+convert+RGBColor+to+wavelengths

Comment: Can you include any code  you've tried so far?